# Appending text to log.info without changing the actual lines

Tags: c#, log4net

I currently have many lines of log.info() in my code. Now I wanted to know if there was a way that I could add an extra variable to that line without changing all the lines in my code. For example , suppose I have something like this in my code

```
int trackno;
log.info("Object has passed stage 1");
log.info("Object has passed stage 2");
...
```

Now is there any way in which I could print the trackno in the log without changing the actual logging code. I am looking for an alternative way of doing this

```
log.info("Object has passed stage 1 - Trackno = " + trackno );
```

Comment: You are only changing the argument that gets passed into the log.info method, you are not changing the logging code. Why don't you want to change the argument?

Comment: Because there are many lines on my document which would be time consuming. I was just curious if there was a better way.

Comment: You could always extend upon the log.Info class and add an optional parameter, so you only have to change the ones where you want extra info.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like...

```
log.Info(string.format("Object has passed stage {0}",trackno.toString()));
```

Comment: I prefer using `log.InfoFormat("Object has passed stage {0}",trackno);`.  I know you said you didn't want to change the logging code but not sure there is a way around that.  Or if you want to always log certain things in every log message you could use ThreadContext variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap a method around the statement like the following:

```
private void LogInfoObjectPassed(int trackno, int stage)
{
    log.info("Object has passed stage " + stage + " - Trackno = " + trackno);
}
```